# Weird value and overriding text on variadics

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm trying to create a logging system where you push a log string into a vector and then print all the logs by looping through the vector, but there seems to be an issue where the strings inside my vector are getting replaced by the most recent string pushed, as well as weird characters being added.

```
struct color {
    color(unsigned int nr, unsigned int ng, unsigned int nb, unsigned int na) : r(nr), g(ng), b(nb), a(na) {}
    unsigned int r, g, b, a;
};

struct info {
    const char* text;
    float time;
    color col;
    info(const char* ntext, float ntime, color ncol) : text(ntext), time(ntime), col(ncol) { }
};

class event_logger {
public:
    std::vector<info> info_list;
    
    void add_log_messasge(color col, const char* message, ...) {

        char fmsg[512] = { '\0' };
        va_list list;
        va_start(list, message);
            vsprintf_s(fmsg, 512, message, list);
        va_end(list);

        this->info_list.push_back(info(fmsg, 10.0f, col));

        // limit to 12 messages at a time
        if (this->info_list.size() > 12)
            this->info_list.pop_back();
    }

    void print_log_info() {
        /* Don't run if the vector is empty. */
        if (!info_list.empty())
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < info_list.size(); i++)
            {
                printf_s("%s\n", info_list[i].text);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    event_logger log;
    log.add_log_messasge(color(255, 255, 255, 255), "welcome (%.3f, %s)", 3.14f, "WHAT THE FUCK");
    log.add_log_messasge(color(255, 255, 255, 255), "unlucky %s", "dude");
    log.print_log_info();
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: `fmsg` is a local variable with a lifetime of the function it is in. `this->info_list.push_back(info(fmsg, 10.0f, col));` stores a pointer to that local variable. When you go to access it later it is not in scope and you have undefined behavior. Why not use a `std::string` in `info` instead?

Comment: Note that C-style variadic functions aren't the best way to accomplish what you're trying to do. In C++, we have [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) which are safer and give you much more fine-grained control.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Most of the strings I will be passing are const char* so for the time being I just went with that. If fmsg only lasts until its out of scope, how would I resolve that issue? It also has the issue of all the logs pointing to the same string in memory whenever it changes, so all the logs turn out the same.

Comment: "*how would I resolve that issue?*" - by having `info` make a duplicate of the `char*` data it is given, and then free that dupe in its destructor. This also means `info` needs to be updated to follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to manage the dupe properly. Best to just use `std::string` instead, let it do all of the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your struct

```
struct info {
    const char* text;
    float time;
    color col;
    info(const char* ntext, float ntime, color ncol) : text(ntext), time(ntime), col(ncol) { }
};
```

is copying an address to a local variable `fmsg`. The life time of `fmsg` is circumscribed in the scope of `add_log_messasge` (you got a typo).
Storing the address of a local variable and use it externally of its scope is undefined behavior.

use a `std::string` to store the value of `fmsg` by copying it and it will work.

```
struct info {
    std::string text;
    float time;
    color col;
    info(const char* ntext, float ntime, color ncol) : text(ntext), time(ntime), col(ncol) { }
};
```

You need to change your way of printing it by using `c_str()`

```
   void print_log_info() {
        /* Don't run if the vector is empty. */
        if (!info_list.empty())
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < info_list.size(); i++)
            {
                printf_s("%s\n", info_list[i].text.c_str());
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: Your check that is using `empty` isn't really necessary since an empty vector call of `size` returns 0 which will never start your for loop (`i=0 can't be lower of size 0`)